# Rigid fork replacement for Rock Shox Bluto fat bike suspension fork?

Tags: fork, fatbike

I'm considering the purchase of a fat bike with a Rock Shox Bluto Fork. This fork takes a 150x50mm Maxle Light and 150mm hub.

However, since winter is coming and I'll likely be riding in slop and sub-freezing temps which may affect shock performance and increase the amount of maintenance required, I would like to possibly run a rigid fork during the winter.

Are there any rigid forks (steel, aluminum, or carbon) on the market that will accept the 150mm hub standard or would I need to build a totally new front wheel?

Comment: A lot of fat bike forks from Salsa/Surly, e.g. Salsa Bearpaw?

Comment: Agreed, the Salsa BearPaw 150 looks like it should work.  There probably isn't a lot out there.  I think the default standard for fatbike front has been 135 for a bit.

Comment: Probably "a lot" was the wrong term. Bearpaw is aluminum. A few others I found with a quick Google search were: Surly Ice Cream Truck (steel) is now 150 in the front, looks like Framed sells the Alaskan (aluminum), and LaMere sells some carbon fiber thing.

Comment: Check out Borealis Echo, it was announced yesterday as rigid Bluto alternative. There are also options from China, judging by posts on mtbr.

Comment: You could upgrade the Bluto rather than swapping it out: http://fat-bike.com/2014/12/turnagain-releases-extended-temperature-range-seal-kit-for-the-rockshox-bluto/